# AWS Config stuck at "Currently in progress" when deploying with AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-config

I want to use AWS CDK to deploy AWS Config. The deploy gets stuck at:

```
Currently in progress: AWSConfig, MyCfnConfigurationRecorder, MyCfnDeliveryChannel
```

[image: 1]

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_config as config,
    aws_iam as role,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    RemovalPolicy
)
from constructs import Construct
import os,sys, json

class AWSConfig(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # create role arn for AWS Config
        config_role = role.Role(self,"Role",
            assumed_by= role.ServicePrincipal("config.amazonaws.com"),
            managed_policies=[
                role.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name('service-role/AWS_ConfigRole')
                ],
            role_name="AWS_Role"
        )
        # Create S3 bucket store AWS Config Snapshot and GuardDuty Finding
        s3bucket = s3.Bucket(self,"MyBucket",
            encryption= s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
            block_public_access=s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
            bucket_name="guardduty-config-finding",
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
        )
        # Create AWS Config
        cfn_configuration_recorder = config.CfnConfigurationRecorder(self, "MyCfnConfigurationRecorder",
            role_arn="arn:aws:iam::09xxxxxxxx:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig",
        # the properties below are optional
            recording_group=config.CfnConfigurationRecorder.RecordingGroupProperty(
                all_supported=True,
                include_global_resource_types=False
    )
        )
        cfn_delivery_channel = config.CfnDeliveryChannel(self, "MyCfnDeliveryChannel",
            s3_bucket_name=s3bucket.bucket_name,
        # the properties below are optional
            config_snapshot_delivery_properties=config.CfnDeliveryChannel.ConfigSnapshotDeliveryPropertiesProperty(
                delivery_frequency="TwentyFour_Hours"
            ),
            name="delivery-channel"
        )
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Wait until stack update fail - it will eventually, then add error message to post

Answer (score 0):

The deploy is failing because your role is missing some required IAM permissions.

[Here are the IAM policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iamrole-permissions.html#iam-role-policies-describe-apis) the Configuration Recorder requires. The S3 policies are required. The SNS and KMS policies are required only if you are using SNS as a delivery method or SSE-KMS to encrypt the bucket.

Add them to your role as `inline_policies: aws_iam:PolicyDocument`.